Geometry Nodes: Detect if an Attribute is Unassigned
In this case, I would like to only delete a mesh if the color attribute is black, but not if the attribute is unassigned/None. My guess is that geometry nodes interprets null attributes as black. Attribute statistic seems to me like the closest to what I am looking for, but not quite.


AFAIK, there is no such thing as "null" attributes. They must have a name, and when created, no matter what you do it will have a default value (the one you plugged or the default value of the slot). What about using a boolean attribute which stores if the attribute is null or not ? If you don't have a color that you can use as null value, I don't see any other solution.

Thanks for sharing those options. In my case, I setting the default value to white fulfills my needs.
